# How to cause a termination of background process started from .xsession(rc) when I'm logging out?

Tags: debian, x11

I start a background process from my `.xsessionrc` script like this:

```
my_process &
```

As a process, it is owned by x-session-manager.
Looks ok.
But when I log out from my session the process isn't terminated. It keeps running as a top-level process. Why does it happen and how to start my process in a way that guarantees a proper termination?

My system is Debian Bullseye + Mate Desktop.

UPDATE: Process ownership and process group for me look correctly:

```
 PID    PPID    PGID COMMAND         
1848    1781    1848 x-session-manag 
1913    1848    1848 my_process
```

Comment: Is the process owned by your username or by root?

Comment: @KenJackson It is owned by me